# Linear Layout Height and Weight

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have the following

```
<linearLayout>
<RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Header -->
</RelativeLayout>

<linearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="6">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

</linearLayout>
```

However the layouts are not assuming to fill the height properly I wish to for the desired effect of one linearLayout below another and to take up 1/6th of the parent space.

Instead it seems to be applying the weight to the width of the element.

What is the correct method to assume percentage height in Android?  Width seems to be a breeze with Weight but I can't seem to get it correct on Height.

Comment: Looks correct to me... Oh, try specifying `orientation:vertical` on the parent `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I have the same problem, with a twist. In my case the root linearlayout has mix of linear layout, framelayout and relative layout. Any clue where I am going wrong. I have specified the orientation in all the linear layout.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add `android:orientation="vertical"` in your `LinearLayout` as by default it is `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

Comment: It works but I my case: I have 3 linerLayout inside of other and them do not have the same height