# How to fill The Android screen with views and layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

[image: Problem Image]

I have a Relative Layout Containing following Views and Nested Relative Layouts. For Some devices there is a blank space left at the bottom of the screen. I want to equitably distribute the space to the nested views and `viewgroups()` to fill the Screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/tdmubiobgd"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MasterActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ScanButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Scan" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/scan_adsView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/ScanButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ads" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/scan_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scan_adsView"
    android:layout_below="@id/scan_adsView"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Scan_Image"
        android:layout_width="72px"
        android:layout_height="72px"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Scan_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Scan_Image"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Scan_DName"
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="DName "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Scan_Sex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Scan_Name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Scan_Age"
        android:text="Male"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Scan_Age"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Scan_Sex"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Scan_Sex"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Scan_Name"
        android:text="30"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/scan_level1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scan_header"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scan_header"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/l1warning" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/scan_master"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scan_level"
    android:layout_below="@id/scan_level1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scan_mname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MinionRush"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scan_mdetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scan_mname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scan_mname"
        android:text="DoodlePlay"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scan_period"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scan_mdetails"
        android:text="DartRace"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/scan_alarm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/alarm" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/scan_level2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/scan_master"
    android:layout_below="@id/scan_master"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:src="@drawable/toempty" />

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/scan_gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/scan_level2"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/faq"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/scan_gallery"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/faq" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What are those specific devices?

Comment: .Android AVDs and all handsets I tried

Comment: How can you assign android:layout_weight="1" for ImageView when Parent layout is Relative layout & orientation variable for Relative Layout?

Comment: @ShashankAgarwal I have changed that. Put it to android:layout_height="wrap_content" as I did it the first time and removed the android:layout_weight="1"

Answer (score 2):

Use the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#556677">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:background="#664411"/>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#997766">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you....

Comment: Can I ask why you're using `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`?

Comment: yup... The complete layout is divided into four equal parts.. Now if we wont give it as fill parent then you have to give it as wrapcontent. By making it wrapcontent again height of each part will depend upon the height of the content. So to make the height of each part independent of the content we have to give it as fillparent...

Comment: @Augustus Francis: Did you try this?

Comment: I see. Isn't the whole purpose of assigning weights to views is to distribute remaining free space? Since the `LinearLayout's` orientation is `vertical`, the distribution of space will happen from screen's height. So, you're better off setting `android:layout_height="0dp"`. The point is: giving value to `android:layout_height` is redundant. `0dp`(conventionally) makes it easier to understand.

Comment: @Shane: Yes. But Its not working. Also I got a lint error saying that using android:layout_height="0dip" gives better performance. I coulnd not use a Linearlayout as RootViewGroup instead I used RelativeLayout.

Comment: Please See the Updated Question with the Code

Comment: Well Augustus can you plz tell me the reason why you can not use linear layout? Another thing why is it not working? Instead of Imageview and other widget you can use relative layouts in same way and use all your widgets in those layouts....

Comment: Looking at your code, diagram and your question, be more specific as it is conflicting..

Comment: @Shane The code I have given doesnt fill the screen. I want it to fill the screen. 
I could use Linear Layout but in that case wouldn't I be needing a lot of layouts.

Answer (score 1):

use linear layout as your parent layout and give weights to all layouts.

Comment: @ArmaanStranger weight is for the height too! http://stackoverflow.com/a/10846835/1482726

Comment: I was reffering to the downvoter of your answer which falsely commented that weight in linear layouts affect only the width. He removed his comment but not the downvote.

Comment: @Shrikant I think This should work.. I have to rewrite a lots of code to work around it. I have used RelativeLayout as the ParentLayout. Is there any workaround?

Comment: @cyberwalker So is there anyway I could fill the screen without weights if I use RelativeLayout.

Comment: It can be done but not efficiently with "hard code" , But i would suggest you not to take that path if you are making apps for various screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a XML for your question

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_weight="1">
</RelativeLayout>

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_weight="1">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Copy paste this xml, And then tell me if it is working or not? Or post Your XML to help you specifically .

Comment: to use android:layout_weight we need to specify either ** android:layout_height ** or ** android:layout_width ** as ** "0dip" ** depending on whether you need to fill the Height or Width of the device or Layout. Since I need to fill the device's height I should have tried this:  
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"  
I have tried this method many a times with positive results but now I am in trouble..

Comment: that is not necessary to set your height/width 0dip.
And FYI : your problem has been solved , IF you are not getting desire result then try to run your application on device instead of emulator,

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout     
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="1">
</RelativeLayout>

<Gallery
android:id="@+id/gallery1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="1"
/>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="1">
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

use linear layout and add
 `android:layout:weight="1"` 
in every tag..
if you want to use the Relative layout then,it is better that you should get the screen dimension and divide it into four, if you have four views

Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18374695/2681950) for getting screen size

Comment: @ArmaanStranger weight is for the height too! http://stackoverflow.com/a/10846835/1482726

Comment: Yup i was reffering to the downvoter of your answer which falsely commented that weight in linear layouts affect only the width. He has removed his comment.

Comment: @Ansar:This should work.. I have to rewrite a lots of code to work around it. I have used RelativeLayout as the ParentLayout. Is there any workaround?